# positive and negative results on the same row

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

Hi I have data in two columns(Category, Name, number) some names has positive and negative numbers. I would like to have data on the same row if the category is same.

```
Category   Name   Number
-------------------------
A          xyz     10
A          qwe     -10
A          uio      20
A          ghj     -20
```

Result should be

```
Col1   col2   col3   col4
--------------------------
xyz     10    qwe   -10
uio     20    ghj   -20
```

I would like to do this in SSRS.

Comment: would be better if you use pivot in SQL query to achieve this.